# Appium inspector does not see accessibility id of XCUITest Driver elements

Tags: ios, automated-tests, appium

Appium inspector doesn't see the accessibility id of the element (like textfield) https://prnt.sc/me4s5k (only xpath of element is finded) but accessibility is enabled on Xcode https://prnt.sc/me4t4y. Also some elements (only buttons) is finded with accessibility id by inspector https://prnt.sc/me4sir.

My iOS developer says that you can interact with an element using the Object-ID. How can I do this with Appium for the tests on Java?

Or, how should a developer sign text fields in Accessibility form on Xcode for elements to be visible in Appium?

Answer (score 2):

You can use ..

> driver.getPageSource();

You will be able to see (the driver view), all the element IDs/Objects ..